# Does MySQL update indexes on virtual columns on tables that are being replicated from a master?

Tags: mysql, replication, index, virtual-columns

We use statement based bin log master-slave replication with MySQL 5.7.
We use the slave for analytics and so add additional indexes and things not required on the master.
I recently tried to add a virtual column and indexed it.
Unfortunately, it seems that none of the new data being replicated ends up in the index.
When I query the new rows, the generated column values are present and correct but when I filter the table on the generated column values, none of the rows created since the index was created are returned.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this not supported with bin log replication?

Comment: Specifics, please.  Let's see, for example, version number of both MySQLs; the sql to add the virtual column and index; which flavor of replication is being used (RBR/SBR/Mixed); `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on both Master and Slave; and maybe some other things.